# AngularJS component binding doesn´t work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding, components

I am testing my first component binding in AngularJS, but I can´t make it work, and I can´t see where is the issue.

I have two components: one to get an user list, and the other to show each user´s details. The second component must be inside the first component´s view, but nothing is shown, no user´s details (in this case, only the name).

The code:

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app="mainMod">

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="micss.css"/>

</head>

<body>

    <comp-mostrar-listado></comp-mostrar-listado> 


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>


    <script src="./miscomponentes/mostrarListado/mostrarListado.js">       </script>

    <script src="./miscomponentes/mostrarDetallesUser/mostrarDetallesUser.js"></script>


    </body>

</html>
```

Now I have one folder called "miscomponentes" with the two components, each one consisting on an .js file with the component and an .html file for the view.

**First component code:**

**mostrarListado.js**

```
var modListado=angular.module('modMostrarListado',[] );

    modListado.component('compMostrarListado',{


    controller:'contMostrarListado',
    controllerAs:'listado',
    templateUrl:'./miscomponentes/mostrarListado/view-mostrarListado.html'



    });


    modListado.controller('contMostrarListado',function($http){



    var vm=this;

    var peticion=$http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');

    peticion.then(

        function(respuesta)
        {
            vm.lista=respuesta.data;

        },

        function(respuesta)
        {
            alert("error");

        }

    );


});
```

**view-mostrarListado.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in listado.lista" >{{item.name}}</div> <!--this  works-->


<comp-mostrar-detalles-user ng-repeat="item in listado.lista"  usuarioIndividual="item"></comp-mostrar-detalles-user><!--this doesn´t work-->
```

**Second component code** (the one into the last view)

**mostrarDetallesUser.js**

```
var moduloMostrarDetallesUser=angular.module('modMostrarDetallesUser',[]);

    moduloMostrarDetallesUser.component('compMostrarDetallesUser',{

    bindings:{

        usuarioIndividual:'='
    },
    templateUrl:'./miscomponentes/mostrarDetallesUser/view-mostrarDetallesUser.html'


    });


angular.module("mainMod",['modMostrarListado','modMostrarDetallesUser']);
```

**view-mostrarDetallesUser.html**

```
<div>{{$ctrl.usuarioIndividual.name}}</div> <!-- it doesn´t work neither with $ctrl nor without it-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using binding you need to separate capitalized words with dashes "-" so it should look like this:

```
<comp-mostrar-detalles-user ng-repeat="item in listado.lista"  usuario-individual="item"></comp-mostrar-detalles-user>
```

So I've put everything on plnker so you can check it out:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ABzmuC6rR1FyMptFSzO7?p=preview

Cheers,

Comment: It works! The blank spaces are actually not in my code, maybe I pasted wrong here. Why must I use usuario-individual in the component tag, but then to display each object´s name I have to use {{$ctrl.usuarioIndividual.name}} again?

Comment: that is correct you use capitalized names on variables on controller and only in templates when you pass through binding you use dashes, similar to what you do when you declare component in template you use capitalized declaration on .component(...) and then in template you use dashes.